# Tracking the linux config with git: how?

Tags: linux, git, configuration-management

I'd like to track my linux configurations with git.

- My idea is to have a **branch for each server**.
- `/etc` is not the only one directory to be tracked (I won't `git init` in '`/etc`' )

As far as I could see, it is possible to init a git for a distant directory.

I tried this:

```
# mkdir -p /git/.git
# cd /git
# git --work-tree=/ --git-dir=/git/.git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /git/.git/
```

1) Creating a new branch before everything is not possible

```
# git branch server1
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'HEAD'.
```

2) adding a file in master/HEAD is not possible

```
# touch README.md
# git add README.md 
fatal: Unable to create '//.git/index.lock': No such file or directory
```

how should I properly setup git to track my system-config ?

Thanks.

P.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do it by hand, you could use etckeeper: http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/

which is specifically made for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper configuration management tool e.g. [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/), [chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/) or similr and store their configs in git.

This may have an initial cost but it's smaller than havimg to go back and fit it all at a later date.